# why doesn't my tomcat docker container deploy the webapp?

Tags: tomcat, docker, deployment

i just want to start a simple tomcat docker container and mounted my warfile into it.
command:
`docker run --name tomcat_server -p 8080:8080 -p 8009:8009 \`
`-v /c:/p/webapps/sample-webapp.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample-webapp.war \`
`-d tomcat:8`

but i always get a 404 error:

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

after the container is started and i jump into it with `docker exec` and i only found the war file `sample-webapp.jar` but not the folder `/sample-webapp` (as it is on my "real local" tomcat)

docker tomcat webapps folder:

> drwxr-x---  3 root root  4096 Oct 10 08:42 ROOT
>   drwxr-x--- 14 root root  4096 Oct 10 08:42 docs
>   drwxr-x---  6 root root  4096 Oct 10 08:42 examples
>   drwxr-x---  5 root root  4096 Oct 10 08:42 host-manager
>   drwxr-x---  5 root root  4096 Oct 10 08:42 manager
>   drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    40 Oct 19 10:55 sample-webapp.war

why doesn't tomcat deploy that war file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For volumes under Windows use either

`-v C:/my/local/path:/my/container/path`

or

`-v /c/my/local/path:/my/container/path`

And you also have to allow your `C:` drive to be shared with Docker inside your Docker settings:
[image: Docker settings]

Comment: thank you for your help! this is a volume under windows, so i need the `:`. the mount it self worked because i got the war file into the container, but the container didn't create the new folder for the app. i identified an usual docker problem with mounting volumes. don't know why this sometimes appear. i just removed all my containers and then reseted docker to factory defaults and now it works. :(